# OAuth2 in Asp.Net core for web application by calling AuthenticationApi - Http Error 500.3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0

I am introducing OAuth2 to my existing Asp.Netcore 3.1 web Application

What I am trying to implement here is

I wrote login Authentication validation in separate rest webApi
with Url's - https://localhost:555/token && https://localhost:555/api/test/resource1

When a user try to access the web application in Program.cs changed

```
public static void Main(static[] args)
{
      string oAuthInfo = Program.GetAuthorizeToken().Result;
      Log.Information("Starting up");
      CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}
public static async Task<string> GetAuthorizeToken()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
                var allInputParams = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
                allInputParams.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", "Anurag"));
                allInputParams.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "123456"));
                allInputParams.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"));
                var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localjost:44322/token") { Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(allInputParams)};
                response = await client.SendAsync(req);
                response.IsSuccessStatusCode
            }
            return response;
        }
```

Above step we are validating the credentials and generating the token from webApi

But while running the web application in my local  I am getting the below error.

[image]

Am I doing in right way? Any design changes needed. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can't actually spin up the application due to an exception.  Have you debugged your startup code?

Comment: Check the event log of system to find the root problem.

Comment: Put some breakpoints in the code and see where it blows up.